# set values with events

Tags: javascript, events, closures

I am writing a quiz application with remote server (i have a "start" URL for the question that I get with fetch, there I can find the next URL which i use to send the answer object with html POST request, get the URL for the next question, etc). I am stuck with how to send the values from these two functions to another function (which is async if that is important).
So i have the following functions:

```
  isStringAnswer () {
    let answer
    this.questionField.innerHTML = `
    <input id="answerInput" type="text" placeholder="enter your answer">
    <button>Ok</button>
    `
    const input = document.querySelector('#answerInput')
    const button = document.querySelector('button')
    button.addEventListener('click', e => {
      answer = input.value
      console.log(answer)
      return answer
    })
    console.log(answer) // undefined
  }

  ifAlternatives (obj) {
    const alternativesDiv = document.querySelector('#alternatives')
    alternativesDiv.innerHTML = '<button>Ok</button>'
    for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj.alternatives).length; i++) {
      // creating radio buttons (it works perfectly fine, so I reduced some code
    }
    const button1 = document.querySelector('#alternatives button')
    button1.addEventListener('click', e => {
      var ele = document.querySelectorAll('.Buttons')
      console.log(ele)
      for (let i = 0; i < ele.length; i++) {
        if (ele[i].checked) {
          console.log(ele[i].value) 
          return ele[i].value
        }
      }
    })
  }
```

I also have the app.js where i call the function. The all work on their own, but I can't put them together. I need to pass the value from isStringAnswer() and ifAlternatives() to another function so I can use it in the object "answer { answer: SomeAnswer }" which is in another function. Basically I just need to use the variables i get from event handlers. For now if I assign them to the variable I get undefined, which is logical, but I don't know how to rewrite them.

That is not well explained I guess, but I will update the info if you have any questions.

Comment: fixed I think :)

Comment: I fetch a question with the only URL i have, check if it is a simple or multiple answers question => if it is a simple question I call the function to receive the input from the user (isStringAnswer) / if it is a multiple choice question I call ifAlternatives function and get the value from the chosen alternative. In both cases I need to return a value - answer - that I pass to a function that sends the request back to the server, if the answer is correct, i get a URL for the  next question and I call the very first function again but with this "next" URL. Hope that makes sense

Comment: No, one client and a remote server (I don't know how it processes information). I only know that I have to send a request with an object { answer: *someAnswer* } and I don't understand how to get this answer value from the function that gets user input

Comment: So you never change the page and you load the questions as and when the answers, so you can keep all the answers on the client computer and consult them as you wish, so no need to send them by a message from the station client on himself ...

Comment: yes, exactly. So it's a pretty simple app, but I am stuck with this

Comment: Keep your values in a global, or eventualy in the localstorage